# How do I see RTs in a Twitter list?

Tags: twitter, list

Is there a way to show RTs in a Twitter list?

If I look at [one of my lists](http://twitter.com/po8crg/politics) on Twitter.com, then I only see tweets from the people actually on the list.  Obviously, I see old-style RTs because the API doesn't distinguish them from tweets by the original user, but I don't see new-style RTs from those users.

Is there a setting on my account or on the list that will show RTs in the list?

Comment: I think this is rather a bug than a feature you are missing, try contacting Twitter support so they can fix this behavior or provide an option to toggle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to see the RTs in just a list you've made, but it is possible to see *just* RTs of people you follow.

So, on the new and old versions of the Twitter site, there's a Retweets option in the navigation. On the old site, it's on the right hand side under Favorites, and on the new version, it's a tab at the top. You can view RTs by you, by others, and your tweets that were RT'ed.

You can also find a Twitter client that you can make actual RT lists with, such as [Tweetdeck](http://support.tweetdeck.com/forums/63876/entries/84531).

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected the answer would be "no" - but there you go!  Will leave open for a while in case someone finds a real answer.

Comment: Related: Is it possible to disabled RT's in lists with Tweetdeck? http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26562/10026

Answer (score 1):

Since this was raised you can now actually see retweets as part of a list's timeline.

This change must have occurred some time around the end of May or the start of June 2014.

You currently cannot set if you want to see these retweets or not as part of a Twitter list.