# In TweetDeck, is it possible to disable retweets in a list?

Tags: twitter, retweet

I've set up a Twitter List and when viewing the list directly on twitter.com, list member retweets are not shown. This is my expectation for a list.

However, when using Tweetdeck (either web.tweetdeck.com or the Chrome app), I'm seeing retweets by list members in the list column.

Is it possible to disable this behavior, so that Tweetdeck operates like twitter.com?